# VS Setup Project - Change install language

Tags: visual-studio, localization, installation

How do I change the localization of a setup project in VS2008 to be other than the defined languages in the dropdown (i.e. not English or France but Hebrew or Dutch)

Thanks,

Yoni.

Comment: I'm interested in the same thing. Our customer wants a Dutch installer, and I can't do find a way to do that in VS2008.

Answer (score 1):

I believe VS2005 only supports the following Localization languages:
Neutral
English
French
German
Italian
Chinese (Simplified)
Chinese (Traditional)
Japanese
Korean
Spanish

"Text for deployment properties must be entered using characters from the code page for the 
target locale or a build error will occur. The code pages supported for deployment are: 1252 (Neutral, English, French, German, Italian, and Spanish), 936 (Chinese (Simplified)), 950 (Chinese (Traditional)), 932 (Japanese), and 949 (Korean)." -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcx25hzz(VS.80).aspx